# How to fix the "Multipart request" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input to upload files and I want to save the file in a server. I used postman and everything works fine but its in the code where things get  messy. Im getting this error everytime I click the button

"{"httpStatus":"Internal Server Error","httpStatusCode":500,"status":"ERROR","message":"Current request is not a multipart request"}"

my code:

```
const handleFile= (data) => {
    setFile(data.target.files[0]);
    
  };


  const sendJson = () => {
        formdata.append("file", file);

           const requestImage = {
             method: "POST",
             headers: myHeaders,
             body: formdata,
           };

           fetch(urlFiles, requestImage)
             .then((response) => response.text())
             .then((result) => console.log(result))
             .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
           }
return ( 
      <input
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          id="upload-photo"
          name="upload-photo"
          type="file"
          onChange={handleFile}
          inputRef={register}
        />
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                typeof={"submit"}
                onClick={(() => sendJson())}
                >
                Registar
              </Button>
)
```

What this error means and how can I fix this? I tried some solutions like adding  enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag but nothing is working. Please help me with this

Comment: it depends on how your api you are calling accepts the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of making a multipart request using fetch is as follows,

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('myFile', fileInput.files[0]);

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
}).then(res => response.json()).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

DO NOT set the Content-Type header. The browser will set it for you along with something called disposition. To learn about multipart forms, I've written a blog on it. https://dev.to/sidthesloth92/understanding-html-form-encoding-url-encoded-and-multipart-forms-3lpa

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Could you please clarify where the fileInput  variable comes from and what happens to the state i used to store the data from the uploaded image??

Comment: Your code's equivalent of `fileInput.files[0]` will be `data.target.files[0]`